# Why is image of prime ideal under Hecke (Grossencharacter) character is prime element of the local field?

Tags: algebraic-number-theory, arithmetic-geometry, elliptic-curves

Let $K$ be a imaginary quadratic field, and $E/K$ be elliptic curve which has CM over $K$.
Let $ψ_E$ be Hecke(Grossencharacter)  character of $E/K$.
Let fix prime ideal $I$ of $K$.
Then, why $ψ_E(I)$ is prime element of $K_I$(K's completion at $I$) ?

Back ground : I heard formal group of $E$, $ \hat{E}$ is Lubin Tate for **prime element** $ψ(I)$, but it seems not clear to me why it is prime element of local field $K_I$.

Comment: Hit: if $h$ is the class number of $K$, then what can you say about $\psi(I)^h$?

Comment: In this situation, automatically $h＝1$, so it is just $ψ(I)$.

Comment: Could you give me one more hint ?

Comment: Sorry, I meant to let $h$ be the order of the *ray* class group modulo the conductor $f$ of $\psi$. Then $I^h$ is trivial in the ray class group, so $I^h = (\lambda)$ for some $\lambda \in K^\times$ with $\lambda = 1 \bmod f$. Hence $\psi(I)^h = \lambda$. So what can you say about the valuation of $\psi(I)$ at the prime $I$? Or at any other prime?

Comment: I want to prove is $ord_I(ψ(I))＝0$. $ord_I(ψ(I)^h)＝ord_I(λ)$ so $h・ord_I(ψ(I))＝ord_I(λ)$. On the other hand, $h＝ord_I(λ)ord_I(a)$ for some ideal $a$ thus $ord_I(ψ(I))＝1/ord_I(a)$ , but this  cannot be  $0$ so I'm confused.

Comment: You're trying to prove $\psi(I)$ is a prime element, so you definitely don't want its valuation to be 0, you want it to be 1.

Comment: @David Leffler  By the way, codomain of Hecke character is $ \Bbb{C}^{×}$. ' $ψ(I)$ is prime of $K_I$ ' makes no sense to me because the codomain is not $K_I$ which is not embedded to $ \Bbb{C}^{×}$, where am I missing ?

Comment: Ok, thank you. Then $1/ord_I(a)$ should be $1$ because it takes value group $ \Bbb{Z}$. Using your argument, can we relate $ψ(I)$ and $I$ ? $ψ(I)＝λ^{1/h}$, and because $p^h＝λO_K$, can we describe some relation between $ψ(I)$ and $I$ ?

Comment: @bouyant: the Hecke character associated to an elliptic curve over K with CM by K takes values in $K^\times$. If you don't understand this, please ask a new question, rather than jumping in on somebody else's.

Comment: @dandelion: do you know what the infinity-type of $\psi$ is (and do you know what those words mean)?

Comment: @David Loeffler  I didn't know that concept.

Comment: Is that something to do with relation between $ψ(I)$ and $I$ ?